# Contour integral problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a complex function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2-i}$. Find $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz$$ where $\gamma$ is a counterclockwise unit square.

My approach: By Cauchy integral theorem it is $0$,since  $f$ is analytic throughout any domain containing the unit square.
Would it be right to say so? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: at a simple pole $z_0$, the residue of $p/q$ is $p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$. This can save you from a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Are you allowed to use residues?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that $z^2  - i = \left(z-e^{i \pi/4}\right)\left(z-e^{5 \pi i /4}\right)$ and both $e^{i \pi/4}$, $e^{5 i \pi/4}$ are within the unit square. Hence, the function is not analytic inside the unit square.